# Not getting Task List Columns under crawled Property

Tags: task-list, content-search-web-part, crawled-property

I am not able to get the task list fields in my crawled property. I have a field in the task list named "Related Content"and this is a default task list column. Even after running a full crawl I am not able to get this column under my crawled properties.

I have some other custom lists with custom columns and I'm getting those custom column under crawled properties after a full crawl .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some crawled properties will be created using internal names of columns. And the internal name of "Related Content" column is "WorkflowLink".

So, check there will be  **ows_WorkflowLink** and **ows_q_URLH_WorkflowLink** crawled properties for "Related Content" column.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have not enabled search in the LIst settings of the Task List . Once i have made that ,I'm able to get the properties.